# Global variable in Metal Shading Language

Tags: macos, metal

I want to use mouse to control my camera position. The idea is to have a global variable `float3 pos` that carry the current camera position so that the next update will be from the `pos` itself.

When I declare a `global variable` in `Metal`:

```
float3  pos;
```

and get this error:

> Global variable must have a constant address space qualifier.

But if I add `constant`, it become read only thus I cannot update my current position.

An alternative I can think of is using `struct`. But that seems a bit over do.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, only read-only variables (constants) can be defined as globals in `MSL`. You could do this by sending the mouse coordinates from the host (API) code via a buffer, to your shader. In there update the value of these coordinates and then update the buffer so the host code sees your updated values in real time. Here is a [playground](https://github.com/MetalKit/mouse) that shows you the mouse coordinates in the console as you click inside the rendered area.

Comment: Am I right if I say this about your code: send `mousebuffer` and `outbuffer` to `kernel`. `Mousebuffer` always update and `outbuffer` only update when mouse is down?

Comment: correct. however, you can send whichever event (or coordinates) you want from the UI class, including keystrokes.